# Mask all fields of a csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a sample CSV:

```
Name,Birthday
Aman Sharma,12/2/92
```

and I want to mask all the characters in PowerShell i.e.,

```
Name,Birthday
xxxx xxxxxx,xx/x/xx.
```

I have tried

```
(Get-Content .\aliases.csv)|% { $_ -replace  ''  ,'0'}|Set-Content test.csv
```

but what it is doing is adding a 0 after every character like

```
N0a0m0e0,B0i0r0t0h0d0a0y0
A0m0a0n0 S0h0a0r0m0a0,1020/020/09020
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty solution where I use a helper variable to store the first line. However, there is a more graceful solution out there.

```
$content = Get-Content test.csv
$firstLine = $content[0]
$content = $content -replace '\w', 'x'
$content[0] = $firstLine
$content | Set-Content test.csv
```

Comment: Your character class is better

Comment: Beware that `\w` is a [superset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordCharacter) of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, though, so it might match more than what's intended.

Answer (score 2):

`-replace` is an operator that supports regex. `''` or blank in regex matches the empty space between characters. That is why you get the results that you do.

Not sure what the point of masking the CSV is but to get something more closer to what you want, given your sample data.

```
$oldFile = "c:\temp\test.csv"
$newFile =  "c:\temp\maskedTest.csv"

# Read in the file contents
$data = Get-Content $oldFile
# Send the header to file unmasked
$data | select -First 1 | Set-Content $newFile
# Read in all lines after that and replaced the alphnumeric characters.
$data | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "[a-z0-9]","X"} | Add-Content $newFile
```

So instead we replace all characters a though z as well as number 0 though 9.

Comment: Hi Matt. I want to mask the data as there are some account nos. whom i need to hide but keep the format intact.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is probably more elegant than the ones using `Get-Content`, but won't provide as good performance. The difference shouldn't be noticable for smaller files, though.

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
(Import-Csv $csv) | ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
    $property.Value = $property.Value -replace '\w', 'x'
  }
  $_
} | Export-Csv $csv -NoType
```

Comment: I considered something like this. I figure it would be more useful if there were columns you wanted to keep in their original form.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $res=Get-Content C:\temp\test2.csv

   $newres=@() 
   for ($i = 0; $i -lt $res.Count; $i++)
   { 
      if ($i -eq 0)
      {
         $newres+=$res[$i] 
      }
      else
      {
         $newres+=$res[$i] -replace '\w',  'x'
      } 
   }

   Set-Content C:\temp\test2.csv -Value $newres
```